# Object_required:Application(...)

Tags: asp-classic

I'm getting **800a01a8|Object_required:_'Application(...)** error when i'm calling the Application object in .ASP page. When i try to create object in .ASP file with Server.CreateObject("MyApplication.WebSession") its working.

Could you please advise am i missing something?

ASP application is hosted on IIS 8.5

### ASP Page Code

Set WebSession = Application("WebSession")

### Global.asa

Sub Application_OnStart

Set WebSession = Server.CreateObject("MyApplication.WebSession")

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You had not created Application variable inside `Application_onStart` method of `global.asa`.

Right way to set application variable is as follows :

```
Sub Application_OnStart

Set Application("WebSession") = Server.CreateObject("MyApplication.WebSession")

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jadeja, Thank you for the reply. Sorry,      I had set the application variable in Global.asa file already. as below                                                                                                                             Set WebSession = Server.CreateObject("MyApplication.WebSession")
Application("WebSession") = WebSession                                                            But the issue still persists.Please advise